# How to use interactive Charting and graph in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, database

I want to use interactive charts in my projects.
I have to show all the data in charts .
So that I am finding the interactive charts.

Comment: Refer http://www.amcharts.com/ link. It provides complete guideline.

Comment: try JQPLOT charts http://www.jqplot.com/ its freeware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can help you?

HTML5: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

HTML: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/chart/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

it's very simple use this components.